# Assign result of dynamic sql to variable

Tags: sql-server, string

I'm doing dynamic SQL to convert all columns in a table a string

so After after all I do

```
EXEC(@template);
```

where @template is the dynamic generated query so:

```
col1  col2 col3
---------------
1    7    13 
2    8    14
3    9    15
4   10    16
5   11    17
6   12    18
```

(this results: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18)

How do I assign to a variable the resulting string

something like?

```
DECLARE  @result AS varchar(max);
 SET @result = EXEC(@template);
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use sp_executesql with output parameter.

```
declare @S nvarchar(max) = 'select @x = 1'

declare @xx int
set @xx = 0

exec sp_executesql @S, N'@x int out', @xx out

select @xx
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
1
```

**Edit**

In my sample `@S` is instead of your `@template`. As you can see I assign a value to `@x` so you need to modify `@template` so it internally assigns the comma separated string to the variable you define in your second argument to `sp_executesql`. In my sample `N'@x int out'`. You probably want a `varchar(max)` output parameter. Something like `N'@Result varchar(max) out'`

Here is another example building a comma separated string from master..spt_values

```
declare @template nvarchar(max)
set @template = 
'select @Result += cast(number as varchar(10))+'',''
from master..spt_values
where type = ''P''
'

declare @CommaString varchar(max)
set @CommaString = ''

exec sp_executesql @template, N'@Result varchar(max) out', @CommaString out

select @CommaString
```

Comment: mmm, the same NULL result when I do `select @xx` could it be my @template var the one with any trouble?

Answer (score 26):

Most of these answers use **sp_executesql** as the solution to this problem.  I have found that there are some limitations when using sp_executesql, which I will not go into, but I wanted to offer an alternative using **EXEC()**.  I am using SQL Server 2008 and I know that some of the objects I am using in this script are not available in earlier versions of SQL Server so be wary.

```
DECLARE @CountResults TABLE (CountReturned INT)
DECLARE 
    @SqlStatement VARCHAR(8000) = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table'
    , @Count INT

INSERT @CountResults
EXEC(@SqlStatement)

SET @Count = (SELECT CountReturned FROM @CountResults)
SELECT @Count
```

Answer (score 21):

You could use [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of `exec`.  That allows you to specify an output parameter.

```
declare @out_var varchar(max);
execute sp_executesql 
    N'select @out_var = ''hello world''', 
    N'@out_var varchar(max) OUTPUT', 
    @out_var = @out_var output;
select @out_var;
```

This prints "hello world".

Comment: How do I incorporate my var @template? is it `EXECUTE sp_executesql N'select @out_var = ''@template''', @ParmDefinition, 
    @out_var = @out_var output;`

Comment: @cMinor: If `@template` contains SQL, pass it as the first paremeter: `sp_executesql @template, ...`.  Make sure `@template` is an `nvarchar`.

Comment: One question, I did it, and `select @out_var;` has nothing it says `NULL`

Comment: I also changed @out_var (max) to @out_var nvarchar (max) everywhere, but when doing `select @out_var;` I get `NULL`

Comment: @edgarmtze I also got NULL everywhere for a while, until I dismantled the query - finding that the query was fine, my table was just empty. Hope it helps those looking through here.

Answer (score 2):

Sample to execute an SQL string within the stored procedure:

(I'm using this to compare the number of entries on each table as first check for a regression test, within a cursor loop)

```
select @SqlQuery1 = N'select @CountResult1 = (select isnull(count(*),0) from ' + @DatabaseFirst+'.dbo.'+@ObjectName + ')'

execute sp_executesql    @SqlQuery1 , N'@CountResult1 int OUTPUT',     @CountResult1 = @CountResult1 output;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this while getting SEQUENCE value in a variable from the dynamic table.

```
DECLARE @temp table (#temp varchar (MAX));
DECLARE @SeqID nvarchar(150);
DECLARE @Name varchar(150); 

SET @Name = (Select Name from table)
SET @SeqID = 'SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR '+ @Name + '_Sequence'
insert @temp exec (@SeqID)

SET @SeqID = (select * from @temp )
PRINT @SeqID
```

Result:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
 1
```