# Storing value in variable using dynamic sql in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign result of dynamic sql to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable)

Can you help me to store a value in the given example.

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(20)

declare @table_name varchar(20)='sample_table'

EXEC('SELECT '+@variable+'=SUM(CAST([Annual Plan & GM$] AS MONEY)) FROM '+@table_name+'')
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are getting with the above query? You might want to declare another var called '@SQL', and build the query in that variable. Then you can use EXEC '@SQL'.

Answer (score 3):

You can return a typed output parameter using `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @variable   money
declare @table_name varchar(20)='sample_table'

declare @sql nvarchar(255) = 'SELECT @variable=SUM(CAST([Annual Plan & GM$] AS MONEY)) FROM '+ @table_name
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, 
    N'@variable money OUTPUT',
    @variable OUTPUT

select @variable
```

Comment: Thanks Alex Yah! got the result...