# sql server save result of exec(@query) in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query which returns a single result.

```
  @query='select name from studtable where id=1'
```

How should I write query so that result is saved in string and `@result` contains result.

```
  @result=exec(@query)
```

Comment: you got the answer?? I've noticed you don't accept any answers. Why so?? It's not a good practice..

Answer (score 3):

```
To execute a string, we recommend that you use the sp_executesql stored procedure
instead of the EXECUTE statement. Because this stored procedure supports parameter
substitution, sp_executesql is more versatile than EXECUTE; and because
sp_executesql generates execution plans that are more likely to be reused by SQL
Server, sp_executesql is more efficient than EXECUTE.
```

Read more here:[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

So you can write as"

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @IntVariable INT
DECLARE @name varchar(30)
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @nameOUT = name
                   from studtable where id=@id'
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@id tinyint,
                        @nameOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'
SET @IntVariable = 1
EXECUTE sp_executesql
@SQLString,
@ParmDefinition,
@id = @IntVariable,
@nameOUT=@name OUTPUT
SELECT @name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below to store the result using `sp_executesql` with `output` parameter. Observed from here [Assign result of dynamic sql to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable)

```
declare @ret int
set @ret = 0

set @query='select name from studtable where id=1'

exec sp_executesql @query, N'@var int out', @ret out

select @ret
```