# SELECT FROM Table where the table name is in a variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I save the result of my exeuction into a variable? I want to save the integer given by the count into a variable

```
    DECLARE @count INT

    SET @sqlString = 'SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT process) FROM @tableName
        + ' WHERE process =''' + @process + '''' + 'AND stage ='
        + '''' + @varStage+ ''''

        PRINT @sqlString
    SET @count = EXEC (@sqlString)
```

This is my idea, but the last line does not work.

Comment: does not work? with what error?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign result of dynamic sql to variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable)

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC doesn't return the count value, you need to select @count within the statement


 Create Table #Temp(Number int)
 DECLARE @count INT

    SET @sqlString = 'Insert Into #Temp SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT process) FROM @tableName
        + ' WHERE process =''' + @process + '''' + 'AND stage ='
        + '''' + @varStage+ ''''

  PRINT @sqlString
  EXEC (@sqlString)

  Select @count = Count(*)
  From #Temp
```