# SQL Using results from query (Table Names) to search within identified Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I have not been able to find an answer online yet.  I want to run a query that will identify a subset of tables within a database, and then will run a query against each of these tables individually and give the results. The tables get created on a weekly basis and so I want to be able to run a query against all the tables that cover a certain period.  In effect, I am wanting to create a foreach loop.

The pieces independently work, but I can't get them merged correctly.

Query 1: Tables

```
Select name from DBName.sys.tables
where name like 'Table_Name_2015%'
and is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Query 2: Search within Table

```
Select Top 1000 [Column1], COUNT(*) As ctr
From Table_Name_20151026
Group By [Column1]
Order By ctr desc
```

I also tried having the results from Query 1 go into a table and then trying to call the table in Query 2, but I was not successful.

```
Select name into Table_Collection from DBName.sys.tables
```

I have tried setting the from in Query 2 as a variable but at best I can only get it to pull one table's worth of results.

I have searched through this and other websites and I have found a few more starts which didn't pan out such as sp_MSforeachtable.

Comment: You would need to build the SQL statement dynamically into a string variable then call exec() or sp_executesql to execute it.  If you just had a single table with a date column this would be much simpler.

Comment: Are you trying to query multiple databases or are you planning to change the db name per run of the query? Either way, you will need a loop and some dynamic SQL as @AlexK. suggests. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable : offers a good place to start with dynamic SQL and tempatizing your queries.

Comment: No, all the tables are in one DB.  Unfortunately it is COTS software so I can't change their DB Structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select 'Select Top 1000 [Column1], COUNT(*) As ctr From '+name+' Group By [Column1] Order By ctr desc' as sql
from DBName.sys.tables
where name like 'Table_Name_2015%'
and is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Comment: This just produces a list of select statements in the result set. You should probably also include the functionality to execute those select statements so the OP gets what they need from your answer.

Comment: @Css you are suggesting the OP does not know how to write "EXEC"?