# SELECT into variable, using another variable as the column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select into a variable using a column name that is also stored in a variable, but it just selects the value of the column name instead.

The code below loops through all of the columns for a table and finds the old and new value of each column (part of a TRIGGER). The problem is, instead of assigning the old and new value to the variables, it assigns the value of the @fieldname variable.

```
Set @getColumnName = Cursor For
    Select Column_name From Information_Schema.Columns Where Table_Name = @tablename

Open @getColumnName
    Fetch Next From @getColumnName Into @fieldname 

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        Select @oldValue = @fieldname From deleted
        Select @newValue = @fieldname From inserted

        -- Do something with the values here
        -- @oldValue and @newValue are now equal to @fieldname
        -- Actually want them to be the result of the query
    End
Close @getColumnName
```

Comment: You can't use variables for column names.  You can use dynamic SQL but it's a [little tricky when setting variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512)

Comment: read about `COLUMNS_UPDATED` in triggers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this using Dynamic SQL thanks to D Stanley's suggestion

```
Select * Into #MyInserted From inserted
Select * Into #MyDeleted From deleted

-- New value
Set @SQLString = N'Select @outVar = ' + @fieldname + ' From #MyInserted'
Set @ParmDefinition = N'@outVar varchar(max) Output'

Execute sp_executesql 
    @SQLString, 
    @ParmDefinition, 
    @outVar = @newValue Output;

-- Old value
Set @SQLString = N'Select @outVar = ' + @fieldname + ' From #MyDeleted'

Execute sp_executesql 
    @SQLString, 
    @ParmDefinition, 
    @outVar = @oldValue Output;
```