# update with dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, sql-update

I will explain my question, I use the AdventureWorksDW2012 database to demonstrate my purpose. I want to update the table based on the max date in this table where CurrencyID = 'CNY'
but I get the error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`  I know the error because I use dynamic SQL statement but I should use it with cursor ..any help regarding this issue
here is my code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE
        
       @AverageRate  float 
      ,@CurrencyID  NVARCHAR(50)
      ,@CurrencyDate  DATE
      ,@EndOfDayRate  float
      ,@CurrencyKey  float
      ,@DateKey  float
      ,@MaxDate nvarchar(max)



  Declare update_cursor
CURSOR 
FOR
(select DISTINCT  AverageRate
      ,CurrencyID
      ,CurrencyDate
      ,EndOfDayRate
      ,CurrencyKey
      ,DateKey from dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1 );
OPEN update_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO
       @AverageRate
      ,@CurrencyID
      ,@CurrencyDate
      ,@EndOfDayRate
      ,@CurrencyKey
      ,@DateKey

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
if @CurrencyID = 'CNY'
begin
set @MaxDate = 'select max(CurrencyDate) from  dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1 '
EXEC (@MaxDate)
end

update dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1
set CurrencyDate = @MaxDate
 where CurrencyID = 'CNY'


FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO
@AverageRate
    ,@CurrencyID
      ,@CurrencyDate
      ,@EndOfDayRate
      ,@CurrencyKey
      ,@DateKey
END
CLOSE update_cursor
DEALLOCATE update_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

So far what I could understand from mobile view is you declared @maxdate as nvarchar but trying to store and update date field with it. Please use date data type.

@MaxDate date

Comment: I try to use date  but it is only accepted nvarchar

Comment: whats the dataty of dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1's currencydate field?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to "double use" the `@MaxDate` string. In one place you use it to hold the SQL you are trying to run, and in another place you are trying (but failing to) make it hold what should be the output of executing that SQL.

I would declare these as two variables:

```
@DynamicSQL nvarchar(max)
@MaxDate date
```

Then replace:

```
set @MaxDate = 'select max(CurrencyDate) from  dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1 '
EXEC (@MaxDate)
```

With

```
set @DynamicSQL = 'SET @MaxDate = (select max(CurrencyDate)
                                   from  dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1)'
EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

Comment: I used it for my purpose..because in my real scenario I have the variable @tablename  which store list of the tables from which I get the max timestamp

Comment: if i used it without sql dynamic I got error..                                                 
` set @table = 'dbo.NewFactCurrencyRate1'
set @MaxDate = (select max(CurrencyDate) from  @table)`

Comment: Apologies for the multiple submits, I kept accidentally triggering a keyboard shortcut which submitted. Hopefully what I'm saying makes sense, and you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'm not actually sure the code I've given will work, as I don't think this will set the variable in the calling context. This SO may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable